# Restarting Gnome 3 in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome3

What's the correct way to restart Gnome 3 (and Xorg) under Debian 7.0 Wheezy?

I've seen older documentation on how to this, but it is outdated.

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> shortcut no longer works by default.

Running `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` from Gnome terminal just gives me a blank screen with blinking underscore and never properly reboots the X session.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @JosephR. restarting the x session without rebooting the entire box.

Comment: Then why does `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` not "properly restart the display"? What is "proper"?

Comment: @JosephR. when I do that the terminal just hangs at a blinking prompt. Might be a localized problem but I assumed I was going about things the wrong way.

Comment: Check out my answer. Solves your problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to issue the command for restarting the X server from outside the X session:

- Switch to a virtual terminal using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fi</kbd> with `i` falling between 1 to 6 inclusive (2 to 7 inclusive if you're on Fedora or RHEL).
- Log in at the prompt
- Run `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` or `sudo service gdm3 restart`
- Reattach to the original screen using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fi</kbd>, where `i` is the higher screen number of the original X session, <kbd>F7</kbd> should be the default on Debian

Comment: How do I reattach to the original session? ctrl + alt + f7? Is f7 the assumed default session?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Usually. Although it might be re-spawned on "higher" screens (F8 and upwards). Note that the F1 screen is the default one for the X session on Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a privative graphical driver, probably you must stop and start the service gdm3, cause it will be failed at the start with restart command.