# Cannot bypass login screen with correct credentials and no errors in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, login, root

Today I downloaded the latest VMware image of Kali Linux ([Kali Linux 64 bit VM](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)). After that, I configured the hostname in `/etc/hostname` and adapted also the `/etc/hosts` to set permanently a hostname. Then, I executed the following commands:

```
apt-get upgrade && apt-get update
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install wine32
apt-get install clamav
apt-get install clamav-freshclam
```

and rebooted afterwards. Then, something strange happened. I was no longer able to login with the default credentials `root` and `toor`. Although, I did not get the error message `Sorry, that didn't work. Please try again.`, I could not get past the login screen. However, I noticed that I am able to login when selecting GNOME on Wayland and also booting in recovery mode.

[image: Kali Linux cannot login]

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: looks like it clammed up.

Comment: Maybe that's cause you can't login with root on Kali Linux through GUI - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223961/cant-login-to-using-root-user-in-kali-2-0-sana-after-update

Answer (score 0):

So I take it GNOME worked prior to updating? If not then your setup may not support GNOME 3, like you said, you can use a different GUI like GNOME on Wayland or [install a different one](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?17716-How-to-install-remove-different-Desktop-Window-Manager-in-Kali-Linux-1-x).

Otherwise, take a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, it will hopefully show any logged errors with GNOME. You can also look at `/home/user/.xsession-errors`. You can try to reinstall GNOME, hopefully that will fix any issues. First, create a copy of the virtual drive just incase this causes an issue, then run this:

```
apt-get purge gnome-session
apt-get autoremove 
apt-get autoclean
apt-get install gnome-session
```

Add the `sudo` to the commands above if you're not running as root, but it seems you are. Also you can skip the graphical login by pressing `Control + Alt + F1` then logging in.

I don't think this would apply to a virtual machine, but incase someone else has an issue, take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99549/14349).